# Blender Game cell shading

Tags: mesh

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ss04Dx93Qn0&index=1&list=LLq1KLPD4FszVI0eoW6XFUKw&t=0s

I was following the tutorial above as I am trying to make a Anime style character, After completing the cell shaded cube I tried it on my character and when duplicating the character when I try to scale it up it scales it upwards as appose to every direction.
s[image: Screenshot from Blender]

Is there a way to do this? p.s I am new to blender.

Comment: In the screenshot you are scaling the object in every direction uniformly already. Notice the fingertips are getting further apart as well. If this is not what you want, can you elaborate on what you were expecting to see?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Scale operation works in relation to the object origin - so for a cube with the origin placed at the centre you get the desired effect - ie, you end up with a larger cube with faces parallel to the original and at a consistent distance.

For more complicated models this same technique does not work as you have found. One solution (depending on your mesh) is to use a Solidify modifier with a *negative* Thickness.

[image: solidify]

Another option (if the Solidify doesn't produce useful results) is to duplicate the original mesh and use a Shrinkwrap modifier on the duplicate, set with the original mesh as the Target. Set mode to Project and adjust the Offset for the thickness.

[image: shrinkwrap]